# Android App Tabs How To?

Tags: android, tabs

I am trying to write an android app, actually, have been for some time, but I cannot find the proper documentation on my problem. I do not even know where to start at this point. What I need, is to be able to put tabs into the android actionbar, lets say tabs x,y, and z. And I need each tab to be made up of either an activity or a layout file. so say selecting tab x would show layout 1. y layout 2, and z layout 3. OR x activates activity 1, y activity 2, etc. You get the point. I have been able to do this much. HOWEVER, what I cannot seem to be able to do, is make tab x have say a button that, upon clicking it, will perform some operation. So the heirarchy would be like this.

```
Main Activity
----Add Tabs (x,y,z) to action bar and assign each tab to a layout/activity. 
----Select Tab y
---------Show layout 2, which contains a button
---------click button > starts activity "blah"

Activity Blah
----DO something.
```

I hope that makes sense, but i have searched for over 20 hours and simply cannot find what I need. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

what you want is probably [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)